# Fixed Button below a scrollable ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a scrollable ListView with items (like in http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html). I am using an `ArrayAdapter` for the items and use it as a parameter in `setListAdapter`. Now I would like to add a button at the bottom of the screen, which does not scroll with the list. Could someone give me some hints or post a code snippet how it could possibly be done?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

If your activity extends ListActivity then you need something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_height="0dip"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Notice that the listview has a layout_weight set to 1. That will keep the button fixed in its place at the bottom.

Comment: if you are using `weight` and the `orientation` is `vertical` , so you should have : `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Comment: Houcine, you are right. In one of the recent updates, Google changed the ADT so it throws a warning when using 'fill_parent'. A lot has changed since I answered the question in Jun 2011. I changed my answer and made it current.

Comment: After adding `android:layout_marginTop="20px"` to my button, the ListView doesn't show up anymore, and the button sits at the top of the screen. I removed the `marginTop`, but it's still behaving like this. Is there a safe way to get a tiny space between the Button and ListView? Am I doing this right, or could my code be to blame?

Comment: This only works if you have match_parent on Layout...doesn't work for wrap

Comment: Great solution for wrapping dialogs with a static button at the bottom.

Answer (score 15):

you can use a RelativeLayout to fix the button at the bottom of your layout , and add your listView above it like this :

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <Button android:id="@+id/btn" 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

     <ListView 
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_above="@id/btn" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I generated the ListView by extending the class by `ListActivity` and using `getListView()` to get it. But if I now use a layout and use `setContentView` to set it, the application throws the following exception: `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`

Comment: i think u should custom your ListView when you get it !! can you add your code and the logcat too ?

Comment: name your list android:id="@android:id/list" if you want to use getListView()

Comment: good solution, but ListView will situated bottom while contains few items.

Comment: This doesn't work. If the list fills up, the button remains below the screen

Comment: @YashJain: I think that even if the list fills up, it will always be above the button element (which is aligned at the bottom of the parent layout).

Answer (score 1):

My solution based on Houcline's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6403765/2404181) but `ListView` always above `Button`

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chbRemoveIfUninstall"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/chbRemoveIfUninstall"/>
```